# Camera bag for a Mamiya RB67 ProS

Tags: film, camera-bag, medium-format, mamiya

To any Mamiya RB67 ProS users out there:

I am looking for a small camera bag to carry my Mamiya RB67 ProS. I am only interested in carrying the camera with a 120 film back and the 127 mm Sekor C lens. I am looking for a very small and compact bag. Do you have any suggestions? Do you think I can fit it into [this Bestek bag](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00L22FAS2/)?  (Amazon.ca listing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you think I can fit it into this Bestek bag?

The dimensions given for the camera insert are: 8"x4.7"x6.7"

So... get the gear you want to carry, arrange it about as you would in a bag, and get busy with your ruler. It's possible that the dimensions given are outside dimensions, so take that into account.

This procedure will help you evaluate any bag.

Comment: Okay I got cracking with a ruler and found the dimensions to be:

Comment: Length: 9'' Height: 5.5'' Width:5.5''. So it definitely won't fit in the Bestek bag. Thanks for your encouragement! If you know of any affordable bags that might work let me know!